# How to install Warsow?

Tags: software-center, games

I'm trying to install some Linux-based games and I came across Warsow.
Downloading it from the USC didn't work because there was no such package (?).

On the website of Warsow I found a guide on how to install it on Ubuntu.
This is what it says to do (all as sudo):

```
wget -O warsow_1.02_unified.tar.gz http://www.warsow.net/download?dl=linux102
```

then

```
tar zxvf warsow_1.02_unified.tar.gz
```

then

```
cd warsow_1.02
wget -O warsow_1.02_ubuntu12.04.tar.gz http://www.warsow.net/download?dl=precisebins102
tar zxvf warsow_1.02_ubuntu12.04.tar.gz
```

After this I should be able to run the game using

```
./warsow
```

When I do so, it says there is no such command.
Now how do I open the game or where can I find it to run it without using the terminal?

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: 12.04 LTS, according to the page I found, it is compatible with this version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way...

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and install the PlayDeb repository by running:

```
echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb games" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playdeb.list
wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then update the package lists and install the game:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install warsow
```

Comment: And how do I open the game now? I tried using ./warsow again, but I get the same error

Comment: Forget about that, it's just in the Dash. Thanks! :)